# How to hide a column in a dojo datagrid dynamically?

Tags: dojo, hidden, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am currently using dojo 1.7. My requirement is that i need to display one column in a grid dynamically based on a particular status. Onload the column should be visible in the grid. But if i am putting one status text field as inactive and searching the column inside that  datagrid should be hidden. I tried various techniques available in the site but many were not matching my requirement while some were not fetching desired results. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. 
any column inside a dojo datagrid can be made hidden by using the below mentioned code.

```
grid.layout.setColumnVisibility(columnIndex,booleanValue);
```